# Invalid DT_NEEDED in Android using a PreBuild .so file

Tags: android, build, android-ndk

i am new with NDK , and would like some help from you. I am trying to run this [Project](https://github.com/ayuso2013/face-recognition-as) but it keeps me showing the Error `Invalid DT_NEEDED entry "../../lib/lipopencv_core.so"`. This may be happening because i am using the .so files compiled by someone else and storing these files in the `jniLibs/armeabi-v7a` folder directly and calling it in the java class with the `System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");`

After reading about this problem([#177](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/177)) i discovered that the file had to be compiled with the `-soname` argument .

But how i do this?
Need to make a Android.mk for this? Or a CmakeList.txt?

I already have installed NDK, Cmake and LLDB.

Ty

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ndk-build (Android.mk) or CMake (CMakeLists.txt) the soname flag is already being handled for you. The problem is most likely that libopencv_core.so was built without this flag. You'll need to rebuild it with `-Wl,-soname,libopencv_core.so`.

Answer (score 0):

This project uses OpenCV v. 2.4.5, built with **android-ndk-r8e**. You can play with it if your device is old enough.

But if you intend to publish an app based on this code, you must rebuild the libraries with the up-to-date NDK toolchain (I would strongly recommend to use an up-to-date version of OpenCV, too).